# Least squares approximation to a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

Consider the inner product space $C[0,1]$ with inner product
$$\langle f,g\rangle =\int_0^1f(x)g(x)\,dx$$
Let $S$ be the subspace spanned by $1$ and $2x-1$

Find the best least squares approximation of $\sqrt x$ by a function from the subspace $S$.

---

My attempt at a solution.

$$\langle x,2x-1\rangle \implies \text{orthogonality}$$
$$\|1\|=1  \quad \|2x-1\|=\sqrt\frac{11}{6}$$

Having found an orthonormal basis for S we find the closest approximation $p$ of $x$ as follows:
$$p=\sum_ic_iu_i \quad c_i=\langle x,u_i\rangle$$
where $u_i$ are the vectors in the orthonormal basis.

So $p=\frac{3}{2} + \frac{-42}{11}(2x-1)$

Is this last bit correct?

Comment: I changed $<x,2x-1> \implies orthogonality$ to $\langle x,2x-1\rangle \implies \text{orthogonality}$ and civilized the typesetting in some other ways.  However, what you write should say $\langle x,2x-1\rangle=0 \implies \text{orthogonality}$, and if its something you'll turn in as homework it should have compete sentences, e.g. "Since $\langle x,2x-1\rangle=0$, these two functions are orthogonal." ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: And if it's true that $\|2x-1\|=\sqrt{11/6}$, then you don't have an orthonormal basis, since $\sqrt{11/6}\ne1$.

Answer (score 2):

$\|f\|= \sqrt{ \langle f , f \rangle }$.

Let $v_1(x) =1, v_2(x) = 2x-1$. Then $\|v_1\| = 1, \|v_2\| = {1 \over \sqrt{3}}$.

Let $u_1 = v_1, u_2 = {\sqrt{3}} v_1$.

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$. Then the closest least squares approximation
is $\phi = \langle u_1 , f \rangle u_1 +\langle u_2 , f \rangle u_2$,
or explicitly,
$\phi(x) =  {2 \over 3} + {2 \over 5 }(2x-1)$.